# VBA- Nested if statements - error 10

Tags: vba, if-statement, excel-formula

I have problem with my simple VBA code.
I have multiple nested if statements (should be included in cells), but unfortunately Im struggling with 1004 error - application defined or object error.

Do you know where is the problem?

```
rejected = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""rejected permanently"", C2)), ""REJECTED"", 
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""unproc.""), D2), ""NOT POSTED"", 
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""NOT POSTED"")), 
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Accepted"", D2)), ""Returned Approved Workflow"", 
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""declined"", D2)),""Returned Rejected Workflow"", 
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Called"", D2)), ""Recalled Workflow"", 
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""succesfully"", C2)), ""POSTED"","""")))))))"

Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = rejected
```

Comment: you are missing the second criterion in the Search: `SEARCH(""NOT POSTED""`